# How add security headers to azure app service for containers

Tags: http-headers, azure-web-app-service, docker-container, hsts

Im having limited success finding how to add custom http security headers (like HSTS) to an Azure app service when deployed as a docker container (linux). Im not sure if this is possible directly on the app service or something like an application gateway is required.

If using kubernetes or swarm i could do this on the reverse proxy ingress, but how can i accomplish this on an app service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 solutions :

1. Go to azure portal and under :

> Your Function App -> Platform Features -> Custom Domain and set HTTPS
>   Only to the desired value (On).

2. Add this to the web.config

> ```
> <outboundRules>
>  <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
>      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
>                 <conditions>
>                     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
>                 </conditions>
>                 <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
>     </rule>
> </outboundRules>
> ```