# How to test Security Headers on App Services within Windows based containers?

Tags: windows, azure, header, azure-web-app-service, hsts

I have set up HSTS on my web application. It is an angular app with a .net backend, hosted on Azure App Services in windows containers. I made changes to the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); //.FromDays(60); //.FromSeconds(31536000);
});

services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});
```

Chrome internals is showing: dynamic_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS.
I cannot figure out how to set up other security headers for an Azure App Service within a Windows container:

- X-XSS-Protection
- X-Frame-Options
- X-Content-Type-Options
- HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)
- Referrer-Policy
- Feature-Policy
- Content-Security-Policy

Comment: `Windows based containers` , Where and how you have deployed your App ?

Comment: You can add the headers either in `Program.cs` or in the `web.config` file.

Comment: You can add like below `app.Use(async (mycon, sh) =>
{
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    await sh.Invoke();
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Security Headers` either from `Program.cs` or in `web.config` file.

In `Program.cs` file, add the below code

```cs
app.Use(async (mycon, sh) =>
{  
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("Feature-Policy", "camera 'none'; microphone 'none'");
    mycon.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';");

    await sh.Invoke();
});
```

***OR***

I have taken references from this [blog](https://itgala.xyz/implementing-security-headers-in-azure-app-service/) to add security headers in `web.config` file.

- Add a `web.config` file in the Existing Application and add the below setting related to security Headers.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>  
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"/>
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"/>
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="Policy-directive" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="upgrade-insecure-requests; base-uri 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self'; object-src 'none';"/>
      </customHeaders>     
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can also refer the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963587/how-add-security-headers-to-azure-app-service-for-containers) and [Blog](https://tomssl.com/how-to-fix-the-http-response-headers-on-azure-web-apps-to-get-an-a-plus-on-securityheaders-io/)  which explains how to add the Security Headers from `web.config` file.

***Output:***
[image]